# dev_appserver.py run on fqdn hostname

Tags: google-app-engine

How do I run dev_appserver.py to run on `http://fullyqualifieddomainname:8080` other than `http://localhost:8080`

I am running dev_appsever.py via ssh in a vm in the cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all this is not a supported configuration and is highly discouraged for performance and security reasons. You might want to check if it violates the licensing terms in your jurisdiction.

However, if you insist and you do it for testing purposes etc this should do it

```
dev_appserver.py --host ipaddress
```

The ipaddress should be the address where the fullyqualifiedname resolves to.